# Is there anyway to overwrite og:image content url on page load, so that overwritten image is visble on preview. I need to show diff preview images

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend

Is there anyway to overwrite og:image content url on page load, so that overwritten image is visble on preview?

I need to show a dynamic image to my video preview.

I have below HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Vertical Tours" />
     <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://skill-store-video-widget.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/metadataspace.png" />
    
    <meta property="og:description" content="Browse Our Properties, Room by Room in Immersive Videos" />
    <meta
      name="keywords"
      content="Video Tours, Vertical Tours, Real Estate, Real Estate Video Tours"
    />
    
  </head>
<body> bla bla bla.. </body></html>
```

While I am sharing a link of this html over chat platforms (whatsapp, slack..), I want my og:image to dynamically change. I tried scripting but on sharing it doesn't execute.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A bit short on informations... Code sample? Framework used?

Comment: Have you try to add random number on the image's link everytime the page load? example metadataspace.png?r=xxxx

Comment: yeah added but problem is how to put value of variable r in meta tag, consider this link is shared on whatsapp where Javascript doesn't run